# Compute the PDF of $X$ if $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed over the unit disk

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, density-function, marginal-distribution

> Let $X,Y$ be random variables and $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed
>   over the unit disk. Find the density function $f_X$.

Well, it is given that $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{\pi}$ if $(x,y) \in S^1$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Hence, $$f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x,y)dy = \int_{-1}^1 \pi^{-1}dy  = 2 \pi^{-1}$$ for $x \in [-1,1]$ and $0$ elsewhere.

But, this seems wrong, as it isn't a density function. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Hatcher's [tag:algebraic-topology]'s book uses $D^1$ instead of $S^1$ to denote the unit disk.

Comment: Please use the correct joint PDF, namely, $$f(x,y)=\pi^{-1}\mathbf 1_{x^2+y^2<1}$$ and the result should follow readily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems to have misused the $f$. For each $x\in\left[-1,1\right]$,
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{1}{\pi}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{\left[-\sqrt{1-x^2},\sqrt{1-x^2}\right]}(y).
$$
Therefore,
$$
f_X(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{\pi}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{\left[-\sqrt{1-x^2},\sqrt{1-x^2}\right]}(y){\rm d}y=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\rm d}y=\frac{2}{\pi}\sqrt{1-x^2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x,y) dy = \int_{-1}^1 \color{red}{1_{S^1}(x,y)} dy  = \frac1\pi \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dy = \frac{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\pi}$$